# Are the levels in PHP CodeSniffer inherited?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

In PHP CodeSniffer, do the different levels of fixers inherit from each other? E.g. if I run with level `psr2`, does it include all the fixers in `psr1`?

I've found that running with `--level=symfony` and then running again with `--level=psr2` and `--dry-run` shows that no further changes are required on the second run which strongly implies that the `symfony` level has applied everything from `psr2` but I'd really like to know for certain.

I've also been browsing through the code but I can't find any clues as to whether the levels inherit from each other.

Comment: If you are using --level, then you are using PHP-CS-Fixer, not PHP_CodeSniffer. For PHP_CodeSniffer, the answer is: yes, PSR2 applies all checks and fixes for PSR1 as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant Fixer. Thanks for this confirmation.